# why the select schemas options doesn't appear on my mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, schema, reverse-engineering

[image]

Hello I want to draw a E-R diagram of existing tables automatically but as seems on ss the shemas doesnt appear on reverse engineering option. How can I solve that?

Comment: SQL Developer and MySQL - does that work?

Comment: sorry I accidentally pasted my other question, it is in right form now, can you help me

Comment: Which tool are you using? a MySQL one?

Comment: yes MySQL the reverse engineering option

Answer (score 0):

Thats why I was using the database that created automatically named as sys. To use the reverse engineer option you have to create a new database(Create database ...) and then you can create automatically E-R diagrams with reverse engineer option under the database button.